# Dealing with Split() function: how to adjust for either return/tab input

Tags: ms-access, split, delimiter

I currently have a serial number inventory database I am working on. I was using the split() function with a space delimiter to separate the data into individual data points, however the scanner I use uses delimiters of either 'return' or 'tab'

Is there any way to use either of those functions in the split() function??

I don't believe tab is possible because tab jumps to the 'next' button... so when the scanner inputs for example (data1 [tab] data2 [tab] data3 [tab]) into the textbox, my output is simply "data1"... I believe because then access utilizes the 'tab' button and just moves from my textbox to the next item. Effectively, it won't even display any data past the first set because it sees tab and moves on. Any way to change this?

Secondly, I can change the scanner to input return or the enter key as scanners delimiters, creating:

data1
data2
data3

in my text box.

Is there any way I can alter the provided code to analyze the lines of the text box and store the information that way (maybe... set each line to i and then run the below code.

I hope this makes sense! My current code that worked for space delimiter data was:

```
Dim InputString() As String
Dim i As Integer
InputString = Split(InputName, "    ")
For i = 0 To UBound(InputString)
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO InventoryInputT(InputID) VALUES ('" & InputString(i) & "')"
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't understand your question's comments about tabs moving to the next button, because a tab within a string is just the same as any other character.

However, if what you are asking is how to split a string containing tabs (i.e. `Chr(9)`s) as delimiters, you can use

```
InputString = Split(InputName, vbTab)  ' to split on Chr(9)
```

For "return" characters, you can use one of the following, depending on what sort of "return" character it is

```
InputString = Split(InputName, vbCr)   ' to split on Chr(13)
InputString = Split(InputName, vbLf)   ' to split on Chr(10)
InputString = Split(InputName, vbCrLf) ' to split on Chr(13)&Chr(10)
```

Obviously, you could also use the actual `Chr(x)` instead of the various constants if you wanted to.

Comment: It was more with respect to how the scanner actuall 'input' its 'block data' into my textbox.

For instance,
If I uploaded my data to excel (every keyboard tab moves to next cell rather than tab space) then my upload data for the above 3 data points would actually enter into excel as 3 sparate cells... whereas what your referring to was more along the lines of: the data should be in 1 cell separated IN the cell by a tab space. 

It was more of a quark of the scanner input itself rather than error with access, so I used the 'return' setting wit the 's' character as the delimiter. Thanks!