# Altering Access to use either tab/return as a delimiter for split() function

Tags: vba

```
Dim InputString() As String
Dim i As Integer
InputString = Split(InputName, "    ")
For i = 0 To UBound(InputString)
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO InventoryInputT(InputID) VALUES ('" & InputString(i) & "')"
Next i
```

Thus, an entry of

```
data1 data2 data3
```

In the textbox of the form resulted in a table input of

```
record1   data1
record2   data2
record3   data3
```

Which is desired. The scanner we purchased uses either a 'tab' delimiter or a 'return'... it can also use 'add jump line' but I don't know what that means and it seems to be similar to return (on the surface)

Is there any way I can alter my code to either:

1) use the tab function
- the issue here is if the data in the scanner is represented as: 'data1 [tab] data2 [tab] data3'

and then I upload that to the textbox, access seems to read the data as:
-input 'data1'
-execute [tab] (which means it navigates out of my textbox to whatever the next button is)
... because it has navigated out of the textbox it can no longer enter 'data2' in the textbox... as such I don't know if this can be solved

2) Can I use the return setup as it allows each data entry to have its own unique line in the textbox
- can I adjust my code so it sets each line of the textbox to a value of i and then runs through my execute code? Example:

data entered (as displayed in textbox)

```
data1
data2
data3
```

Get code to read it as:

```
data1 = line1 = i=0 - execute to table
data2 = line2 = i=1 - execute to table
data3 = line3 = i=2 - execute to table
```

or something along those lines?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with Split() function: how to adjust for either return/tab input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008609/dealing-with-split-function-how-to-adjust-for-either-return-tab-input)  (This must be a popular scanner!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the Split() function is called Delimiter. This can be set to a single space, multiple spaces (as in your example) or even a tab character (vbTab in VBA). It's very flexible.